# I can access my Windows Server 2008R2 via RDP when I enter in the internal IP address, but I can't when I enter in the external IP address

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, macbook-air

I own and have full administrator access to a Windows Server 2008 R2. (It's basically a old laptop that I installed a new OS on thanks to Microsoft's Dreamspark program) I'm trying to setup the Remote Desktop Connection on my Macbook Air, on which I do not have any type of administrative rights (I'm not even allowed executable rights, if the program didn't come with the computer, then I can't use the program). However, the Mac does have a Remote Desktop Client made by Microsoft (v2.1.0). I'm actually renting the Mac from my school district at a rate of $40  per year. As a part of the deal, there's web censorship involved. Basically, all of the "fun" websites are blocked. (Twitter, Facebook, Reddit etc.) So, I decided to set up my make shift server to handle RDP connections. I can access it when the two computers are connected to the same network and I use the internal IP address as the connection address (192.168.1.11). However, when I use the external IP address (in the format of 12.34.56.78), the client refuses to connect. (they're still connected to the same network) I did set up port forwarding 3389 to my server. I did open up the appropriate ports on the server. But I still can't access the server. It just gives me the error "Remote Desktop Connection cannot verify the identity of the computer that you want to connect to." The subtitle says "Try reconnecting to the Windows-based computer, or contact our administrator." Just for kicks, I did type in a incorrect password and the same error appeared. So, I'm stuck at the moment. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: It could be because the server's certificate specifies the internal IP address.  You can tell the server which certificate to use with the Remote Desktop administration tools.

Comment: How would one do this?